# How to do device placement for some model in tensorflow.contrib.slim

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use the pretrained resnet_50 in my model and I want to specify GPU:1 for all the ops in resnet. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

here is my code:

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim
with slim.arg_scope(nets.resnet_v1.resnet_arg_scope()):
    features, _ = nets.resnet_v1.resnet_v1_50(inputs, num_classes=None)
```

and I try

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim
with slim.arg_scope(nets.resnet_v1.resnet_arg_scope()):
    with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
        features, _ = nets.resnet_v1.resnet_v1_50(inputs, num_classes=None)
```

It doesn' work. I find a function named VariableDeviceChooser, but I don't know how to use it.

Help me please~

Answer (score 0):

If the method you cited doesn't work, you can also use an arg_scope to specify the device of the different ResNet ops:

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim
with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.batch_norm, slim.max_pool2d], device='/GPU:1'):
     with slim.arg_scope(nets.resnet_v1.resnet_arg_scope()):
          features, _ = nets.resnet_v1.resnet_v1_50(inputs, num_classes=None)
```

This code snippet will tell slim to put all conv, BN and max_pool ops on GPU:1, I believe ResNet only contains these ops.